# How do I remove the white space in a python code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal, sys

I'm using the following code:

```
import time
import sys

def delay_print(s):
  for c in s:
    sys.stdout.write(c)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.25)

def Loading():
  load = int(10)
  while load != 0:
    delay_print("...\r   \r")
    load = load - 1
    time.sleep(0.5)

Loading()
```

This works fine but is there any way I can remove the white space it shows when using the `\r` command?

Comment: Neat! i like your approach

Comment: What white space?

Comment: Minor note (not even a suggestion, just another way to solve your problem): The separate uses of `sys.stdout` (and the import of `sys`) can be avoided by replacing the two `sys.stdout` uses with `print(c, end='', flush=True)`. Similarly, just for mildly more idiomatic Python, the `while` can just be `while load:` (all non-zero numbers are truthy, zero is falsy, so unless `load` can be something other than an `int`, omitting the `!= 0` changes nothing), and the subtraction can avoid duplicating the name with just `load -= 1`.

Comment: Even more idiomatic: `for _ in range(10):` The value of `load` doesn't actually matter, only that you repeat the loop 10 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have to undestand there is that the `\r` parts of the string are control characters - `\r`, named the "carriage return" control character, which has decimal code "13" and can also be written as the hexadecimal encoding `\x0c` signals the *terminal* emulator program (the program whose window is where there is a central text area where your Python code is executed) interprets it as "return the (printing) cursor to the beginning of the current line".

Unlike more sophisticated control codes, to do things like colored text or arbitrary positioning in other lines, this one works by default even on Windows' badly aged `cmd` default terminal.

So, the reason the whitespace is there is that, if the new string to be reprinted in the same line is shorter than the previous string there, the remaining characters of the old string would not be removed - and the information would be mangled. Like, if this was being used to display a clock, if after "23h59" one would print "0h00", the result in the terminal would be "0h009" (with the "9" uncovered from the previous string, as the new one is just 4 characters in length)

On this code, there is a pause between each character, and the whitespace is just there to erase, by being printed over, each of the previous dots.

So, while this code could be rewritten in a way to have the number of needed whitespace in a variable, instead of 3 hard coded spaces in the string, one would still have to print one space character for each "." or other character it wants to erase on the terminal output.
Even for more complexes text-user-interface (TUI) programs, that is still true: outputting a space character is what is in fact "erasing" a character cell. (Other unicode characters that have no glyph could be used instead - but these are not evenly supported across various terminal programs, and don't have the same semantic meaning as an "empty character cell")

Here is the same script, replacing the " " for a naive logic which counts the printed characters and erases one char at a time:

```
import time

def delay_print(s):
  count = 0
  for c in s:
    print(c, flush=True, end="")
    if c == "\r":
        time.sleep(0.25)
        for i in range(count):
            print(" ", flush=True, end="")
            time.sleep(0.25)
        print("\r", flush=True, end="")
    else:
        count += 1 
        
    time.sleep(0.25)

def Loading():
  load = int(10)
  while load != 0:
    delay_print("...\r")
    load = load - 1
    time.sleep(0.5)

Loading()
```

(It also replaces the use of `sys.stdout.write` by the standard `print` function with the arguments needed to print one character a time in a synchronous way)

Comment: When i try to use this code it removes the functionality of the `\r` command whilst just printing `...`

Comment: Ah, it was missing updating `count` - I updated the code now. As it is in the text, this is a bit of overkill for such a simple, fixed string, and you might as well just keep it as it is.